# How to read equation for summing probabilities of each member in a set?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I’m reading through a [chapter](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter3/3_1_3_pmf.php) in https://www.probabilitycourse.com

There is a section ...

> Consider a discrete random variable X with range $Range(X)=R_X$.  Note that by definition the PMF is a probability measure, so it satisfies all properties of a probability measure. In particular, we have
>
> - $0 \leq P_X(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$, and
> - $\Sigma_{  x \in R_X}P_X(x)=1$

How do I read the bottom equation? Is it ...

*Sum of all the probabilities of X for each x in $R_X$*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sum over all x's which are in $R_x=Range(X)={x \in \mathbb{R}  | x=X(\omega) }$ for some $\omega$ in the sample sample}.

So yes, you read that correctly.